# Django + Scrapy multi scrapers architecture

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, architecture, scrapy

Recently I took over Django project whose one component is Scrapy **scrapprs** (a lot of - core functionality). It is worth adding that **scrapers** simply feed the database several times a day and django web app is using this data.

__Scraper__s have direct access to Django model, but in my opinion is not the best idea (mixed responsibilities - django rather should act as a web app, not also **scrapers**, isn't it?). For example after such split **scrapers** could be run serverless, saving money and being spawned only when needed.

I see it at least as separate component in the architecture. But if I would separate **scrapers** from Django website then I would need to populate DB there as well - and change in model either in Django webapp or in scraping app would require change in second app to adjust.

I haven't seen really articles about splitting those apps.

What are the best practices here? Is it worth splitting it? How would you organise deployment to cloud solution(e.g. AWS)?

Thank you

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a big discussion and I have the same "good problem".

**Short answer:**

I suggest you that if you want to separate it, you can separate the logic from the data using different schemes. I did it before and is a good approach.

**Long answer:**

The questions are:

- **Once you gather information from scrapers, are you doing something with them (Aggregation, treatment, or anything else)?**

If the answer is **yes**, you can separate it in 2 DB. One with the raw information and the other with the treated one (which will be the shared with Django).

If the answer is **no**, I don't see any reason to separate it. At the end, Django is only the visualizer of the data.

- **The Django website is using a lot of stored data that for the Single Responsibility you want to separate it from the scraped data?**

If the answer is **yes**, separate it by schemas or even DB.

If the answer is **no**, you can store it in the same DB of Django. At the end, the important data will be the extracted data. Django maybe will have a configuration's DB or other extra data to manage the web, but the big percentage of the DB will be the data crawled/treated. Depends how much cost it will take you to separate it and maintain. If you are doing from the beginning, I would do it separately.

Comment: Thank you ferran87, those are very good points!
In fact, there is kind of data processing & small ML applied, so second DB could be nice option. Also Django consumes almost only data from scrappers - so second 'yes' answer.